# how to deploy war file to Glassfish on port 80?

Tags: deployment, glassfish, indexof, port80, war

When I deploy my application, I can access to my website at the adress: domain.com:8080 but I want to access with the adress domain.com:80.

When I try to access to domain.com, I found a page "index of" with different folders (my .war) but not website. Can I configure something on glassfish, what I need to do?

help me I'm desesperate

Answer (score 1):

To run your app under 80 port you have just to adjust your listener from 8080 to 80 and make the your app as default web app in the virtual server :

log first on the GF admin panel ( default domain.com:4848 )
then go to left menu :

### (*change port to 80*)

1 - **Configuration** -> 2 - **server-config (default)** -> 3 - **network Config** -> 4 - **network Listeners** -> 5 -**select your listener (http-listener-1 if default)** ---> 6 - **then change the port to 80 and save** .

### **(*make it default app*)**

same thing but make change in default virtual server :

1 - **Configuration** -> 2 - **server-config (default)** -> 3 - **virtual servers** -> 4 - **server (by default)** ---> 5 - **then select your app in the default web app  and save**

after those restart the server and try .

here are some image so they can help you (sorry screen shot in french)

Config port 80 :

[image: config port to 80]

make your app as default in virtual server :

[image: make default web app]

Comment: no idea why it is not accepted as an answer or upvoted. great answer